# Chat profile avatars width wrong with alt text

Tags: bug, chat, design

[image: Picture of issue in chat]

As you can see above, Ben doesn't have a profile picture. This is expected for me, as his picture is being blocked by Ghostery for me. I have gravatar whitelisted but not other sites, and his happens to be pulled from another site.

The space where his image would be, however, is not properly allocated. It is replaced by the alt text, which, for a short username is ok (not the proper spacing, which is bothersome for layout of the rest of the row, but doesn't look *that* ugly (but a little)) but for a long name, it can take up quite a bit of space.

It'd be great if the width for avatars was specified by the styling so that my chat pane didn't look funky when a user with a blocked photo join the discussion.

On Firefox 32, though I would imagine this isn't limited to one browser.

Comment: Filed as a bug instead of a feature request because technically anyone can hit this if one of the services serving avatars goes down or has issues.

Comment: The width and height of an image should be specified in its HTML attributes, not the styling. ;)

Comment: @animuson Except the width and height will vary based on if you have the user muted or not. Otherwise, that would have been my suggestion. Though, that should probably be additional, and then overridden by CSS

Comment: [You should always specify a width and height on an image.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247685/should-i-specify-height-and-width-attributes-for-my-imgs-in-html) I can't tell you how many times I've just closed a page that had a bunch of images without them and everything kept moving around on the page as they were loading. No. Thanks. May not be that important in a chat user list, but always specifying them is a very good habit to follow.

Comment: I get this too. Firefox Aurora 34.0a2, also using Ghostery to block Facebook, and anyone with a Facebook avatar shows up like this for me.

Comment: Sorry to have caused a fuss...